# What is the boxy plastic housing around spade connectors called?

Tags: batteries, connector

This spade connector is used to connect to 12V SLA batteries, and I believe it's the F2 variant.  However it has a nice plastic shroud around it which makes it easier to remove from the batteries and since it's fitted after the crimp it doesn't get damaged as some alternative shrouds do.

I am trying to find where to buy these covers (with or without the female spade connectors) however I'm having trouble because I don't know what they are called!

Does anyone know what retailers label these parts as?

[image: Housing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most often they are called just

> Hard plastic 6.3mm female blade terminal cover

and code for it  RS63004X, where X is a colour code, e.g  RS63004R for Red.

Check this [link](http://polevolt.co.uk/acatalog/6.3mm_Terminals.html)

Also, you can go through all range of [terminal covers on RS website](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/terminals-splices/crimp-terminal-covers/).

Comment: Thanks!  On the RS site it looks like they are also called Faston 250 crimp covers.